# How to create a blob from a base64 string; javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frontend, base64, blob

Basically what the title says; I have a base64 string that encodes an image and I want to convert it into a blob so I can pass it into my `File` constructor. I realise many similar questions have been asked however many of the other answers make use of the `atob` function which has been deprecated; So im trying to look for alternatives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var base64String = "dGVzdAo=";
var blob = new Blob([base64String], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

Comment: this does not work